# TypeORM RelationCount alternative

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm working with TypeORM for a while into a project. 
We have an Entity that holds the followings properties

```
@RelationCount("sentences")
public sentencesCount?: number;

@OneToMany(() => Sentence, e => e.job)
public sentences?: Sentence[];
```

However I noticed that `RelationCount` is depreciated

> @RelationCount, deprecated Do not use this decorator, it may be removed in the future versions

I look for a substitution in TypeORM official readme but I found nothing but creating a custom `QueryBuilder` with a native SQL `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement.

In this project we use a lot of simple statement like `myRepo.find()`. I rather not to replace all these simple calls for `QueryBuilders`.

What should I use instead of `@RelationCount` in our project?

Should I ignore this "depreciate" warning. ?

Answer (score 3):

You need use `loadRelationCountAndMap` methods

```
yourRepository
  .createQueryBuilder("entity")
  .leftJoin('entity.sentences', 'sentences')
  .loadRelationCountAndMap('entity.sentencesCount', 'entity.sentences');
```

And Delete `@RelationCount("sentences")
public sentencesCount?: number;`
from your entity class.

Comment: `loadRelationCountAndMap` doesn't work for me on postgres. also for sqlserver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024634/typeorm-loadrelationcountandmap-returns-zeros

Comment: `loadRelationCountAndMap` works for me and I'm using Postgres.