# Typeorm .loadRelationCountAndMap returns zeros

Tags: sql-server, typeorm

please help.
I am trying to execute the following typeorm query:

```
  return await getRepository(Company)
    .createQueryBuilder("Company")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("Company.plants", "Plant")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("Plant.documents", "Document")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("Plant.notes", "Note")
    .loadRelationCountAndMap("Plant.documentsCount", "Plant.documents")
    .loadRelationCountAndMap("Plant.notesCount", "Plant.notes")
    .getMany();
```

The idea was to select counts of documents and notes per each plant along with all plants for all companies.
(Actually selecting notes and documents themselves was not needed, but i did it to prove that relations do work).

Also I have specified the placeholder variables to keep counts in Plant entity:

```
  @OneToMany(() => Document, (document) => document.plant)
  documents: Document[];
  documentsCount: number;

  @OneToMany(() => Note, (note) => note.plant)
  notes: Note[];
  notesCount: number;
```

Strangely the returned Plant.documentsCount and Plant.notesCount are 0 (while the collections of documents and notes are not empty and are being selected).

Another strange thing is that i don't see in SQL querires any attempts to select these counts, thus i hope typeorm itself would do counting (since it has collections selected correctly).

Could anybody please give some advise on how to select these counts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately Typeorm is the most impotent framework. All important features are either deprecated or not implemented.

To solve this particular issue i had to:

1. Select collections themselves:

```
   .leftJoinAndSelect("Plant.documents", "Document")
   .leftJoinAndSelect("Plant.notes", "Note")
```

2. Add calculations and redundant relation array deletion:

```
  @AfterLoad()
  getDocumentsCount() {
    this.documentsCount = this.documents.length;
    delete this.documents;
  }

  @AfterLoad()
  getNotesCount() {
    this.notesCount = this.notes.length;
    delete this.notes;
  }
```

3. Decided to never ever use TypeORM.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my project is forced to use `typeorm`. You can try the following:

```
@Expose()
get documentsCount() {
    return this.documents.length;
}

@Expose()
get notesCount() {
    return this.notes.length;
}
```

**Discuss:**
But it looks like you're doing an API? You should return this array (documents & notes by `leftjoin`), and then, frontend can seft-caculate by use `.length`. Frontend is currently quite powerful, will share the burden with the server.

```
.leftJoinAndSelect("Plant.documents", "Document")
.leftJoinAndSelect("Plant.notes", "Note")
```